# Jlayer Mp3 player

Tags: java, media-player, mp3, jlayer

I use JLayer to play mp3 files.

I have array of files and I can play the song, go to the next one but I don't know how to go to the next song when first stops.

I have five methods

When song stops I get `playbackEnded` but I can't handle with next song.

That's my code

```
public class SoundJLayer extends PlaybackListener implements Runnable{
    private String filePath;
    private AdvancedPlayer player;
    private Thread playerThread;  

    public SoundJLayer(File file){
    this.filePath = file.getPath();
    }
    public void play(){
    try{
         String urlAsString = 
                 "file:///" 
                 + this.filePath;

        this.player = new AdvancedPlayer
        (
            new java.net.URL(urlAsString).openStream(),
            javazoom.jl.player.FactoryRegistry.systemRegistry().createAudioDevice()
        );

        this.player.setPlayBackListener(this);

        this.playerThread = new Thread(this, "AudioPlayerThread");

        this.playerThread.start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public void playbackStarted(PlaybackEvent playbackEvent){
    System.out.println("playbackStarted()");
    }
    public void playbackFinished(PlaybackEvent playbackEvent){
    System.out.println("playbackEnded()");
    } 
}

public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener,ChangeListener{

    void playNext(){
    soundToPlay.stop();

       soundToPlay = new SoundJLayer(playlist[currentIndex]);
       soundToPlay.play();
    }
```

And I want to invoke `playNext()` when `playbackFinished` but `MyFrame().playNext()` doesn't work

Comment: What do y mean *"can't handle the with next song"*? You got one to start, I'd imagine its the same process again

Comment: @user2466529 What have you tried? It seems that you may simply need to invoke `playNext()` in `playbackFinished`.

Comment: @user2466529 You may take a look at [this code](https://java.net/projects/lg3d-incubator/lists/cvs/archive/2006-09/message/34).

Comment: @lifus I can't invoke playNext() in playbackFinished because playNext() isn't a static mathod. I have playNext() and playbackFinished in different classes

Comment: @user2466529 Could you please give us your code? Otherwise no one will able to came up a with a working solution. e.g. your may declare and instantiate your `PlaybackListener` as an [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) in `Player` implementation where `playNext` is accessible. It's a common Java approach. See code I've linked above.

Comment: I paseted my code class MyFrame craetes and shows GUI I didn't paste it.

Comment: @user2466529 Is there any reason you put `File[] playlist` into `MyFrame`? I guess it belongs to `SoundJLayer` and you shouldn't create new instance of `SoundJLayer` every time. Then you may simply invoke void `SoundJLayer#playNext()` in `MyFrame#playNext()` and `SoundJLayer#playbackFinished(PlaybackEvent)`